# Install Ghidra plugin without GUI

Tags: ghidra, plugin

I have a plugin that I want to install for `Ghidra`.

The current way to install the plugin is to go to the `file->Install Extension` in the project window, and add my plugin there. However, in my scenario, I don't have an access to the GUI and I want to deploy `Ghidra` for Headless Analysis.

For some reason, just copying the plugin files to `<ghidra_home>\Ghidra\Extensions` doesn't do the trick, and it looks like it only partially installs the plugin, and only the GUI way does the complete job.

Any idea how can I programmatically install plugins for Ghidra?

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://ghidra-sre.org/InstallationGuide.html#Extensions) unzipping the extension `.zip` into  the `<GhidraInstallDir>/Ghidra/Extensions` folder should be enough. And it explicitly states that this is the way to go for full headless installs. What do you mean by "only partially installs the plugin"?

Comment: I'm installing the following plugin: https://github.com/astrelsky/Ghidra-Cpp-Class-Analyzer . Upon copying the files to the described folder, I am able to access classes from the extension - for example `from cppclassanalyzer.utils import CppClassAnalyzerUtils` successes, but it is not fully initalized because `CppClassAnalyzerUtils.getManager(currentProgram)` returns None. Only a full isntallation by the GUI makes it return the class..

Comment: I have vague memories of running into some issue like that too with this specific plugin. Turns out I Actually have a local branch of the repo called `plugin_not_activated`, but the changes in that branch aren't quite clear how this would fix it.

Comment: This is most likely some issue with this specific plugin, that branch I had was for this PR https://github.com/astrelsky/Ghidra-Cpp-Class-Analyzer/pull/41.
IIRC `CppClassAnalyzerUtils.getManager(currentProgram)` returns the Service and this Service is only available for within the GUI (specifically in a tool IIRC). I think this would be worth opening on issue about

Comment: Interesting that you say so. However, I think that it is something related to the plugin infrastructure, because, after copying, the GUI asks "New extension plugins detected. Would you like to configure them?" and after saying yes, the plugin works.

Comment: Ah, that might have been why I didn't dig into this further, I'll quickly dive into the code of `GhidraTool.java` to see if there is some obvious way to do this headless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://ghidra-sre.org/InstallationGuide.html#Extensions) unzipping the extension `.zip` into  the `<GhidraInstallDir>/Ghidra/Extensions` folder *should* be enough.

As you specified in the comments the specific plugin this is about is [Ghidra C++ Class and Run Time Type Information Analyzer](https://github.com/astrelsky/Ghidra-Cpp-Class-Analyzer)
 and it only works after going through the initial `"New extension plugins detected. Would you like to configure them?"` dialog on starting the Ghidra GUI.

This dialog is part of the method `ghidra.framework.project.tool.GhidraTool#checkForNewExtensions` and the actual install process happens `ghidra.framework.project.tool.GhidraTool#addInstalledExtensions`.

The problem is that during the headless processing there is no tool available, i.e. `state.tool` is `null` and these methods don't seem to be intended to be run in a headless context. I don't quite understand what specifically makes it work afterwards, but overall I am reasonably confident that this is an issue with the specific plugin, and the fact that it requires the `ServiceManager` to provide the service even for the analyzers (which should be available in headless mode after unzipping).

So this is an issue with this specific plugin which is somewhat hinted at in an already [existing issue](https://github.com/astrelsky/Ghidra-Cpp-Class-Analyzer/issues/18#issuecomment-753588038)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the install directory, you can put the extension into your home directory.

You should manually unzip the extension `.zip` to `~/.ghidra/.ghidra_10.1.1_PUBLIC/Extensions/`. (Replace the Ghidra version with whichever you're using.)

e.g.

```
cd ~/.ghidra/.ghidra_10.1.1_PUBLIC/Extensions/
unzip ~/Downloads/ghidra_10.1.1_PUBLIC_20220127_BinExport.zip
```